# gnu lesser general public license question

Tags: php, javascript, lgpl, 3d

I have a question about Thingiviews license. I have a site that has to do with 3D Printing, it is not done yet but I was wondering if I would be able to use it on my site,

The big reason I am asking is because it will be used to show 3D models that will eventually be made and sold, like shapeways kinda, so I am not selling Thingiview but it would be used to show something that will eventually make money.

Thingiview is currently licensed under:

> GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE

and from what I can gather, it seems that what I want to do should be okay, do I just need to give the creator of it credit? I will either way but it seems that is all that is required.

Is what I want to do okay (by ok I mean legal)?

Also if I want to change it I can do that too right, I have some ideas to add to it. Is there anything I would need to do if I change it a little bit?

Comment: You're asking a bunch of strangers on the Internet for legal advice?  Why not just ask them directly?

Comment: well I did ask the actual author, I just wanted to know about the GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE and how it applies to what i want to do.

Comment: He just has not responded back yet, so thats why, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am not a laywer and this is not legal advice. I recommend consulting with an IP lawyer if you are concerned about possible legal issues.**

Software licenses typically govern the distribution and modification of the *software*, not any artifacts the software may create.

The GIMP software uses the GNU GPL (which if anything is *more* restrictive than the LGPL) and you are allowed to create images and distribute them how you choose, right?

You are most likely okay here assuming the license is not modified or extended.

Caveat: the word "typically" in the first paragraph. Some licenses *do* restrict what you can do with the created artifacts. For example, the free and student editions of Microsoft Visual Studio explicitly forbid selling the programs you create in a commercial setting. However, my understanding is that [OSI-approved licenses](http://opensource.org/licenses), which the [GPL](http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license) and [LGPL](http://opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license) are, do not restrict what you can do with the artifacts created by the licensed software.

Comment: I actually got a response back from the author and according to him, the LGPL says you're free to use it in commercial apps, so long as any changes/improvements you make to the software (the lgpl part) is also released under the lgpl. Thanks for the anwser though.